NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver on KDE Neon
Overview

So I have installed nvidia-driver-470 using sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470 which is recommended by the official website for my GT 730 GPU. Keep in mind I'm a newbie to Linux since I have only used it for one year, thus I read an article about installing this. So I did nvidia-smi as said in the article. As a result I got this beauty:

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Hardware & Software Info


OS: KDE Neon 6.0 running Plasma 6.12
GPU: NVIDIA Geforce GT 730
CPU: Intel Core-i5 6400

Things stated above are all.

470 is not the latest driver.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès Can you provide more info on why that is?
